# React Router goBack does not work on buttonclick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, browser-history

I want to be able to go back to the previous page (just like using the back button in the browser), so I tried using *useHistory's goBack()*, but it does not work.

I imported useHistory:

```
import {
  BrowserRouter,
  Route,
  useHistory
} from "react-router-dom";
```

I wrote this function:

```
function GoBack(){
  const history = useHistory();

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => history.goBack()}>Back</button>
    </>
);
}
```

I get this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'goBack')

This calls GoBack:

```
  function App() {
  const [user] = useAuthState(auth);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <GoBack />
      </header>
      <section>{user ? <ChatRoom /> : <SignIn />}</section>
    </div>
  );
}
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: In order to handle `history` object, where did you place your `routes` for navigation ?

Comment: You should wrap JSX in your App component inside <Router></Router>

Comment: Thank you, indeed all I had to do was put <BrowserRouter> around <GoBack />

Comment: @SlimLamie but without any routes, how can you use back button in your application ?

Comment: I needed it for a specific part that's in plain javascript, so it's a different file.